# Relay Modern compat mode: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'taggedNode[CLASSIC_NODE]')

Tags: react-native, relayjs, relay

Seeing this error when attempting to save a Compat mode mutation.  It seems it may have to do with the Relay-specific part of the query (edge/node).  How can we fix this?

Query is minimally updated from what worked in Relay Classic - only the newWorkoutEntryEdge has been fleshed out to fetch the node and child members.

Mutation code:

```
const mutationQuery = graphql`
mutation AddWorkoutEntryMutation($input: AddWorkoutEntryInput!, 
    $dateOfEntry: String!) {
  AddWorkoutEntry(input: $input) {
    clientMutationId
    newWorkoutEntryEdge {
      node {
        id
        category
        description
        notes
        countOfRepetitions
      }
    }
    userData {
      id,
      workoutEntries(first: 10000,
          dateOfEntries: $dateOfEntry)
        {
        edges {
          node {
            id
            category
            description
            notes
            countOfRepetitions
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}`
;
export default function AddWorkoutEntryMutation(
  notes: string,
  countOfRepetitions: string,
  dateOfEntry: string,
  standardWorkoutID: string,
  userDataID: string)
  {
  const variables = {
    input: {
      notes,
      countOfRepetitions,
      dateOfEntry,
      standardWorkoutID
    },
    // possibly redundant
    dateOfEntry
  };
  commitMutation(Relay.Store, { mutationQuery, variables });
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After tracing this through the Relay code, I realized I was passing an object with `mutationQuery` as a field, rather than `mutation`, so Relay couldn't find the expected mutation field.

Changing this

```
commitMutation(Relay.Store, { mutationQuery, variables });
```

to this

```
commitMutation(Relay.Store, { mutation, variables });
```

solved the problem.